# Verify certificates' fingerprints

Tags: python, ssl, certificate

I am interested in comparing fingerprints of self-signed SSL certifactes. To do so, I thought of:

```
import ssl, socket
from m2crypto import X509

cert_pem = ssl.get_server_certificate(addr)
x509 = X509.load_cert_string(cert_pem, X509.FORMAT_PEM)
fp = x509.get_fingerprint('sha1')
if fp==allowed_fp:
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.connect(addr)
```

But the bias I see, is that the cert might change between the verification and the connection. It would be nice to actually use the same connection `ssl.get_server_certificate` uses. Is there a better way to compare fingerprints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [getpeercert](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert) after connecting.